# Maneuvering through ASP.NET pages in Jsoup

Tags: java, asp.net, jsoup

I've successfully logged in to a page and everything with Jsoup but if I try to navigate pages, it gives me a 500 error

```
    loginResponse = Jsoup.connect(//cut//)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();


    loginResponse = Jsoup.connect(//cut//)
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_txtUserName", name)
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_txtUserPassword", pwrd)
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_ddlLanguage", "ENU")
            .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_btnLogin", "Login")
            .data("__VIEWSTATE" , //cut//)
            .data("__EVENTVALIDATION",//cut//)
            .cookies(loginResponse.cookies()) 
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute()
```

This let me login fine. When i do

```
        loginCookies = loginResponse.cookies();

            String s;
            Document ss = loginResponse.parse();
           // System.out.println(ss.html());
            Element link = ss.select("a[href]").first();

            s = link.attr("abs:href");

            System.out.println("url : " + s);
            Document sss = Jsoup.connect(s).cookies(loginCookies).get();
            System.out.println(sss.location());
```

it prints the URL of the login screen. (s is the right page)

Comment: I've fixed this for now by usng HTMLUnit instead, but I'd prefer to use Jsoup so if anyone has a Jsoup solution post it!

Comment: why do not you give page address? Some pages needs to send cookies and tokens, check what your browse sends with https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/.